# Spyder crashes upon launch on Linux with QtWebEngineCore error

Tags: crash, spyder

[Pic 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1VWWA.png)

[Pic 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FtZM7.png)

[Pic 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tF8qv.png)

[Pic 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gT3F9.png)

This has been happening to me ever since i installed anaconda . I tried spyder --reset, I've tried installing pyqt5.
Nothing worked for me.
Its an Ubuntu18.10 machine. I happened to recently have a fresh install of the OS too and the problem started. It used to run without any error till the last day though upon same configurations. I've already updated my OS with recent updates too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) To fix this problem you need to open a system terminal (xterm, konsole, gnome-terminal, etc) and run there

`conda install pyopengl`

*Note*: This problem will be solved in our next version (Spyder **3.3.0**) to be released in June/2018.

Comment: Thanks for the help.. and sorry for the late reply 

Comment: No worries, that's fine.